# Inverse Laplace transform calculation with steps

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I need to calculate with steps this inverse laplace transform

$\mathcal{L} [(3s+2)/(4s^2+12s+29)*e^{-2s}]$

Unfortunately,I cant factor the dividor and I tried different ways to spit it up (creating ($3s+2)^{2}$ in the dividor) but that didnt get me anywhere. I am really stuck so I would appreciate any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $4s^2 + 12s + 29 = 4\left(s^2+3s+\frac{29}{4}\right) = 
4\left(s^2+3s+\frac{9}{4} + 5\right) = 4\left(s+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + 20$. This polynomial has roots $-\frac{3}{2} \pm i\sqrt{5}$, so $4s^2 + 12s + 29 = 4\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} + i\sqrt{5}) \right)\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} - i\sqrt{5}) \right)$ and
$$
\frac{3s+2}{s^2+3s+\frac{29}{4}} = \frac{3s+2}{\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} + i\sqrt{5}) \right)\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} - i\sqrt{5}) \right)} = \frac{A}{s - (-\frac{3}{2} - i\sqrt{5})} + \frac{B}{s - (-\frac{3}{2} + i\sqrt{5})} = \\
\\ = \frac{A\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} - i\sqrt{5})\right) + B\left(s - (-\frac{3}{2} + i\sqrt{5})\right)}{s^2+3s+\frac{29}{4}} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
A + B = 3 \\
A(-\frac{3}{2} + i\sqrt{5}) + B (-\frac{3}{2} - i\sqrt{5}) = -2
\end{cases}
$$
After doing some algebra, $A = \frac{3}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and $B= \frac{3}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

Now, using $\mathcal{L}^{-1} 
\left(\frac{1}{s - (-\frac{3}{2} \pm i\sqrt{5})}\right) = \exp\left\{
(-\frac{3}{2} \pm i\sqrt{5}) t\right\} = e^{-\frac{3}{2}t}\left( \cos(\sqrt{5}t) \pm i \sin\sqrt{5}t)\right)$, you can get
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} 
\left(\frac{3s+2}{4s^2 + 12s + 29}\right) = 
e^{-\frac{3}{2}t}\cdot \frac{6\sqrt{5} \cos (\sqrt{5}t) - 5 \sin(\sqrt{5}t)}{8\sqrt{5}} \cdot\theta(t)
$$
Finally, because of $e^{-2s}$, apply shift theorem and change argument from $t$ to $t-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica says:

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{3}{2} (x-2)} \theta
   (x-2) \sin \left(\sqrt{5}
   (x-2)\right)}{2 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{3
   e^{-\frac{3}{2} (x-2)} \theta
   (x-2) \left(2 \sqrt{5} \cos
   \left(\sqrt{5} (x-2)\right)-3
   \sin \left(\sqrt{5}
   (x-2)\right)\right)}{8 \sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: yes,I also put it in symbolab and got a similar result but I need to prove it.Sorry for the confusion,edited my post